# Read CSV not detecting heading in Polars - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-polars

trying to read csv file in Polars with only 2 columns, does its job neatly in Pandas, but facing problem in Polars. Appreciate any guidance !

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

kw_path = 'ses_Sestra_keywords.csv' 
df_pd = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=kw_path, sep=";", header=0) # reads just fine

df_pl = pl.read_csv(source=kw_path, separator=";", has_header=True) # gives the trouble
```

Sreenshot of the two -
[image]

The CSV file -

```
kw;desc
DATE;Date and Program Information
IDENT;Identification of a Super Element
IEND;End of a Super Element
UNITS;Definition of the consistent units used in this Sesam Interface file
TDELEM;Name of an Element and/or comment
TDLOAD;Name of a Local Load Case and/or comment
TDMATER;Name of a Material Type and/or comment
TDNODE;Name of a Node and/or comment
TDSECT;Name of a General Eccentric Sandwich Section and/or comment
TDSETNAM;Name of a Set and/or comment
TDSUPNAM;Name of a Super Element and/or comment
TEXT;User supplied Text
TSLAYER;Name of a General Eccentric Sandwich Type and/or comment
BEPS;Beam Element for Plane Systems
CSTA;Plane Constant Strain Triangle
```

EDIT: `eol_char='\n'` doesn't work either.

EDIT_1: csv file [link](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/vxwSrec2#link).

Comment: What version of polars? It works for me on latest `0.18.4`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr0Ad.png

Comment: Hi, Using Polars 0.18.4, same as you. FYI - The csv file was originally written by pandas.

Comment: @jqurious - added the original csv file in Edit_1

Comment: Okay, so the file has `\r` line endings, so `eol_char = '\r'` should work?

Comment: I checked this by opening the file with `newline=''` and printing the `repr()` e.g. `print(repr(next(open('ses_Sestra_keywords.csv', newline=''))))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jqurioud, the csv was originally written by pandas. Therefore adding `eol_char = '\r'` works.